Как подключиться к серверу Firebase через протокол WebSocket
Мне нужно подключиться к серверу, чтобы брать от туда данные, но там WebSocket, а библиотека Firebase для Python, не имеет возможности подключиться к WS адресу. Если же соединяться с сервером через либу WebSockets, то он будет требовать последнюю версию FireBase, вот логи ошибки:
{"t":"c","d":{"t":"s","d":"Version error. Please make sure you are using the latest Firebase library"}}
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionClosedError(None, Close(code=<CloseCode.NORMAL_CLOSURE: 1000>, reason=''), None)>
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: sent 1000 (OK); no close frame received

